# Complex Differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

[image]

Can anyone give a hint to how to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** clearly $e^{\overline{z}}$ is continuous, so you only have to see where the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold. Write: $$e^\overline{z} = e^{x-iy} = e^x\cos y+ i(-e^x\sin y) = u(x,y) +iv(x,y).$$ Check if $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$.

Comment: Perfect! thank you! One more questions, how do i calculate f'(z) at whichever points it is differentiable ?

Comment: If you know that $f$ is differentiable, one expression is just $$f' = u_x + iv_x.$$ You can use the CR-equations to find another (equivalent) expression with $u_y$ and $v_y$.

Comment: Is it also right if i used satisfied the condition ux=-vy and uy=vx?

Comment: No. The CR equations are $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. With the signs **this** way.

Comment: Okay! perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could see if its real and imaginary parts satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  Have you attempted this?

Comment: so far I did, f(z) = e^x(cos(y) - ie^x(sin(y) where u = e^xcos(y) and v = -e^xsin(y) and i followed the lecture notes that were provided by our prof which said ux = vy and uy = -vx but since it it does not satisfy i thought it won't be differentiable.   But i wasnt too sure if my method was correct.

Comment: Try it with $e^z = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$ instead!  Cheers!

Comment: But it's Conjugate of z so shouldn't it be x-iy?

Comment: Oh, I couldn't see the $\bar{}$ on $\bar z$!  Still . . . Also, $\LaTeX$!  Cheers!